# How characteristic length scale affects continuum treatment of matter?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, dimensional-analysis, continuum-mechanics, physical-constants

I understand that by choosing a particular system with a given characteristic length, the smaller the mean free path ($\lambda$) the greater will be the validity of continuum treatment. Thus,

$$Continuum  \, Validity \,\, \,\,\,\, \propto \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\frac{1}{\lambda}$$

I do not understand however that with a given $\lambda$ how increasing the length scale increases the validity of continuum treatment.
i.e.

How $$Continuum  \, Validity \,\, \,\,\,\, \propto \,\,\,\,\,\,\,L_c$$

Answer (score 1):

The smallness of a certain dimensionful quantity only makes sense when compared with another quantity of the same dimensions. The first criterion of the mean free path  being small implies that $\lambda \ll L_{c}$. The implication is that the characteristic length is much larger for the particular scale of the system you are dealing with. For $L_{c}$ in a size scale that is typical for most systems, $\lambda$ attains an "intuitive smallness" that corresponds to typical small lengths in this type of systems. When $L_{c}$ is substantially larger, the smallness of $\lambda$ needn't be small compared to the usual size one encounters, as long as it's much smaller than the scale at hand.

In the way you have written it, the continuum validity criterion is:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\lambda}{L_{c}} \ll 1
\end{equation}